# PHP: Defined Array value undefined

Tags: php

I have an array which I return from a class. It contains data for me which I need in the controller of my application. However something strange is happening. Some values are when I get them by key not defined. But when I print the whole array they are defined. But that's not all. Some keys return their value, some don't.

To test if the key can be found I used `array_key_exists()`, which returned true. Let's get to the example. When I print `$this->case->data`, it will return the following;

```
[id] => 1
[ticket_number] => 2334
[user_id] => 2
[ticket_state] => 1
```

Which is okay. To test this out I tried returning the ticket_number value. (`$this->case->data['ticket_number']`). It worked perfectly and returned it's value. However when I try to return ticket_state (`$this->case->data['ticket_state']`) I get an `undefined` as value.

It might be that I'm missing something here. What am I doing wrong? And if I'm doing it wrong how can it be that `ticket_number` works, but `ticket_state` does not?

**Edit:**

I do get undefined as value returned. Not an undefined index error. I did a var_dump() on the variable.

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["ticket_number"]=> string(14) "2334"  ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2"  ["ticket_state"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

**Edit II:**

My code where I try to receive the value is the following simple if statement;

```
    if($this->case->data['ticket_state'] == 2){
       $this->case->reopen();
    }
```

I've tried adding the `2` in quotes, but since `$this->case->data['ticket_state']` is undefined it the statement will be executed regardless. (Which I found strange too. Why should it still be executed when undefined is not the same as 2 or '2'?).

The current value of my column ticket_state is `1`.

Comment: Do you get the value `"undefined"` or an "undefined index" error?

Comment: might be ticket_state is protected proprty of the class. It will be fine if you could paste the result of `var_dump($this->case->data)`

Comment: I edited my original message and posted the var_dump() result.

Comment: Can you add your actual code where you get "undefined"? Are you trying to access $this->case->data['ticket_state'] within a loop, where one of the arrays have it as undefined?

Comment: @OleHaugset I've updated my original post with the actual code.

Comment: undefined is not a value type in PHP, you can have an undefined index but not an undefined value like in JavaScript, so something is really off here.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the value is `"undefined"` at that point in your code? I don't see how the `if` statement would be executed in that case.

Comment: Are you printing out `ticket_state` after that if statement? what is `$this->case->reopen()` doing?